# Recent Files on Removable Media (There's no such thing)

Tags: files, recentf

Whenever I edit files on removable media, these files disappear from the recent files list, when I remove the media.

When I reinsert the media, I have no recent files for that medium and I have to browse anew.

Is this maybe a setting to eradicate? ;)

Answer (score 2):

Customize `recentf-keep` and set it to `nil` if you don't want *any* checking. `C-h v recentf-keep` says:

> recentf-keep is a variable defined in ‘recentf.el’.
>
> Its value is (recentf-keep-default-predicate)
>
> List of regexps and predicates for filenames kept in the recent list.
> Regexps and predicates are tried in the specified order.
> When nil all filenames are kept in the recent list.
> When a filename matches any of the regexps or satisfies any of the
> predicates it is kept in the recent list.
> The default is to keep readable files.  Remote files are checked
> for readability only in case a connection is established to that
> remote system, otherwise they are kept in the recent list without
> checking their readability.
> A predicate is a function that is passed a filename to check and that
> must return non-nil to keep it.

See also the doc string and the source code of `recentf-keep-default-predicate`. Instead of getting rid of all checking, you might want to define your own predicate that does a subset of the checks that `recentf-keep-default-predicate` does.

Note that if you exit from Emacs and restart it, unreadable files will be purged from the recent file list, so make sure to mount the removable media *before* you start Emacs.